# Is there a way to overload commands in Discord.net?

Tags: c#, discord.net

I have two modules for my Discord Bot: The first one is the `UserModule`, where every commands are, that users can execute, and the second one is the `AdminModule`, where the server admins can customize and set up the bot. Now I got the command `Money` in my UserModule, that makes the bot tell the executor how much money he has. But there's another money command for the admins:

```
[Group("Money")]
    class Credits : ModuleBase
    {
        [Command("add")]
        public void AddMoney(IGuildUser user, int amount)
        {
            int money = Convert.ToInt32(DBConnector.GetInstance().GetDBData
                ($"SELECT Money FROM Users WHERE UserID = {user.Id} AND ServerID = {Context.Guild.Id}")[0]);

            //This will be read from the database in the future
            bool capped = false;

            if (capped)
            {
                int maxAmount = Convert.ToInt32(DBConnector.GetInstance().GetDBData
                ($"SELECT Money FROM Users WHERE UserID = {user.Id} AND ServerID = {Context.Guild.Id}")[0]);

                if (money + amount > maxAmount)
                {
                    amount = maxAmount - money;
                }
            }

            DBConnector.GetInstance().ExecuteCommand($"UPDATE Users SET Money=Money+{amount} WHERE UserID = {user.Id} AND ServerID = {Context.Guild.Id}");
        }
//some more commands
...
```

This is a submodule in the AdminModule and obviously for manually adding or removing money from users. But when I wanted to test the command with `//money add @user 10`, I got the error, that "The input text has too many parameters."
This indicates, that the bot uses the UserCommand instead of the AdminCommand, so I wondered how I can make the bot realize

`"Hey, that command has a usermention and an integer. This is also the case for the admin command. Let me execute that one"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I look at this problem you have two solutions for this very problem.

### 1. Solution

I'd assume that your different users have different roles. Therefor your Admins got a role called `Server Admin` or similar. You could create a custom `PreconditionAttribute` see the [documentation](https://discordnet.dev/api/Discord.Commands.PreconditionAttribute.html) for an example. This attribute could return an Error for all roles provided. This way you could "forbid" the `//money add` command for admins. Then another one which would only allow the admins to execute the admin version of it.

### 2. Solution

This one is a bit more dirty and not recommended. You could only hold on one `Add` Command which would contain the logic for the normal and admin users. With an if statement you could check for their role and decide to do next.

I am pretty sure the first solution would fit better for your needs.

Comment: But if there would be the same commands in each module, and the one in the user-module is restricted to everyone, then I would get a sucess- and an error-message when an admin executes it. Also I wanted to avoid Rolepreconditions in modules, that's why I use these modules. User Module for everyone, Admin Module for admins. If I put an admin command in a user module, with its precondition, then the whole module-setup is useless if I don't stick on the rule "No Role restriction directly on commands"

Comment: Well I see your problem. You could try one more thing tho. Try to add your Modules by hand and not just the whole assembly. You might be able to achieve what you want by changing the order of adding the Modules. I am not sure how it is implemented. You should still give it a shot.

Comment: If this doesn't work, you would either need to write a custom CommandService or use RolePreconditions.

Comment: The strange thing is, I already have a `/Money` command in the UserModule. The user gets his own money as output. And for Admins, I have the same command, but with IGuildUser as parameter. There you get the money of anyone you mention. That works too. After it didn't work, I changed the commands from `Group("Money") -> Command("add"), Command("delete"), Command("info")` to 3 separate commands: Command("Money add"), Command("Money remove"), Command("Money info")

Comment: Just curious what is the difference anyway, why would you want to display something different on the money count for an admin then for a user.

Comment: Well, the user only uses `/Money`, without a parameter to get his amount. He doesn't need a usermention. The Admin uses `/Money @User` so he/she can see the money of the mentioned user. So the admin needs a usermention, the normal user doesn't

Comment: For example: User `@User1` wants to know his money amount. When he does `/Money` he gets the output `You have currently 10 coins`. When he does `/Money @User2`, he gets the output `You are not permitted to do that`. Now the Admin `@Admin1` wants to know his money amount. He can do `/Money` and gets `You have currently 1000 coins`, but he can also do `/Money @User1` to get `User1 has currently 10 coins`. I changed the commands, so `/Money` is just called `Command("Money")`, and the Admin Command is now called `Command("Money info")`. But I want the space, cause `/Money_info @user` looks ugly

Comment: Oh so I think I just now got your problem. What about making your class Money Group class partial and mark the admin commands with a Precondition?

Comment: Documentation link doesn't work anymore.